# android displaying data in Master/ Detail app

Tags: android

I am getting data from the server and have to display them on a Master/Detail App. Do I need to store the data in a content provider and then use loaders to load data or is there some other way..

Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Content providers are used to provide data to other applications.

I would recommend to implement the download in a different thread and then just get a callback from it on the activity to update the data.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a CustomAdapter which gets the data in the way you want to have it. This can happen in AsyncTasks or something like that.